# Receive multiple data from arduino

Tags: arduino

Hello I have a multiple parameters needed to be received by arduino serial port and the format will be like

**a,x,y,z
b,x,y,z**

I want these to be in each array a[] and b[].

how can I neglect the ',' and add in array
how to detect new line?

Answer (score 0):

The end of the line is indicated by `'\r'` or `'\n'` or both, depending on the serial terminal on the other end.

There are three approaches to try:

1. Read the bytes into an array and use sscanf(). Be sure to `#include <stdio.h>`
2. Read the bytes into an array and use strtok() and atoi().
3. Write your own loop to read the characters and construct the numbers.